# Maximum number of permutations

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime, complexity-theory

Some sorting algorithms, like Insertion Sort, have a Θ(n) asymptotic runtime for some subset of the n! possible permutations of n elements, which means that for those permutations, the number of comparisons that Insertion Sort does is kn for some constant k.  For a given constant k, what is the maximum number of permutations for which any given comparison sort could terminate within kn comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

Number of operations in insertion sort depends on the number of inversions. So we need to evaluate number of permutations of `n` values (`1..n` for simplicity), containing exactly `k` inversions.

We can see that `Inv(n, 0) = 1` - sorted array
Also `Inv(0, k) = 0` - empty array

We can get array with `n` elements and `k` inversions:
-adding value `n` to the end of array with `n-1` items and `k` inversions (so number of inversions remains the same) 
-inserting value `n` before the end of array with `n-1` items and `k-1` inversions (so adding one inversion)
-inserting value `n` before two elements in the end of array with `n-1` items and `k-2` inversions (so adding two inversions)
-and so on

Using this approach, we can just fill a table `Inv[n][k]` row-by-row and cell-by-cell

```
  Inv[n][k] = Sum(Inv[n-1][i]) where j=0..k
```

Answer (score 0):

Every comparison at most doubles the never of input permutations you can distinguish. Thus, with `kn` comparisons you can sort at most `2^(kn)` permutations.